# why do we need to use the PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 card for network start?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

A question regarding the "Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)" tutorial. On Step Seventeen, why do we need to use the PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 card instead of the PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1-only card?
I am trying to apply those instructions to a multi organization network on IBM Blockchain platform and getting an error when I try to use the card with all the peers. Things seems to work okay if I use the card with single org peers. But I wondering if there is a specific reason to use the multi org peers card for "composer network start".
Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 1):

As you know (from the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html) you referred to), Org1 requires two connection profiles. One connection profile will contain just the peer nodes that belong to Org1 (-only), and the other connection profile will contain the peer nodes that belong to Org1 and Org2.

The `composer network start` in Step Seventeen, is instantiating the business network on all peers (defined in the profile) to the shared ledger/channel. That channel is contained in the connection.json (which is part of the business network card ) -  ie instantiating it across all (two) Orgs peers on the 'blockchain network'. A prior 'composer runtime install' had already been done, on those peers. The 'start' only needs to be done once for the business network (eg, by Org1 admin in this case).  So the connection profile will contain the peer node info, that belongs to both Org1 and Org2 (ie a component part of the 'PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1' card imported in the wallet). As opposed to: the card called `byfn-network-org1-only` which only has Org 1's peer defined (because typically, you would only be allowed, in the real world - to be able to install Composer runtime on a peer or peers in your 'own' Organisation - and not another's). PeerAdmin has the role / authority to do the runtime install and network start.

It sounds like your cards may actually be 'the wrong way around'  - purely based on what you wrote. Because you will definitely need both peers defined in a card to be able to do Step Seventeen and you would not be able to do it with the '-only' card. I would check your connection profiles and see what's where.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I double and triple checked my cards. I can understand the need for a card/connection profile with peers from multiple orgs if the instantiation policy required the instantiation/start to be endorsed by multiple orgs. But since the default instantiation policy only requires a single endorsement that the transaction was initiated by someone who has channel admin rights, there shouldn't be a need to have information about other peers. May be that is way I was able to execute the step using the '-only' card.

Comment: Naveen, the tutorial doesn't specify the default Fabric policy, and it creates a policy file `endorsement-policy.json` that requires peers from both Orgs (have a read of the tutorial). See hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/… and it has a link to Fabricx docs there ie hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/… . So the tutorial is based both Orgs endorsing :-). If you've customised your env to be different, suggest to read Fabric docs (endorsement policies relate to the underlying Fabric infrastructure - Composer is layered on top :-)